# How to do something after the node is updated in the database?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I want to do something after the node gets updated in the database. I need to be able to hook into the point where the node gets right updated in the database. How can I achieve this?

According to [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7), I need to find a new hook.

Comment: This is what I did at the end. It's not what I had wished for exactly. http://drupal.org/node/1997916#comment-7446502

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rules module, and create a Rule with a code that will execute after create/update/delete. You can also use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7 , but this is called before the node is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the rules event After updating exisitng content?